# How to import Parse JS sdk into ionic 2 beta

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ionic-framework

am trying to import JS sdk into ionic 2 app, but i keep getting parse is undefined

In ionic 1.x ,parse js sdk is loaded via

`<script ..parse.js </script>`

and exposed as a global var, how do import in ionic 2 ,am using the npm module ,and tried

`import * as parse from 'parse'`

Answer (score 2):

Do `npm install parse --save` in your project directory

Then import parse using

`import { Parse } from 'parse';`

It is better to create an parse provider.

You can use this starter template as a guide. It is a simple GameScores application in ionic to get you started.

https://github.com/Reinsys/Ionic-Parse

It shows how to create and read data from parse server. I also includes paging with ion-infinite-scroll scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a solution I came up with my own.
After installing the package and the typings, I opened the index.js of the node-module ionic-gulp-scripts-copy and added  `'node_modules/parse/dist/parse.min.js'` to the `defaultSrc` array.
Then, in my index.html, I included the script above the cordova.js.
Now I just need to `declare var Parse: any;` in every Component I want to use the SDK in. 
For example, in my app.ts:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';

import{LoginPage} from './pages/login/login';
declare var Parse: any;

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
})
export class MyApp {

  private rootPage: any;
  private parse;
  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    //this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log("Platform ready!");
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();

      Parse.initialize('myStartUp', 'someKey');
      Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';
    });
  }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

I do not think this is the way it should be used, but in the end I can use the SDK pretty easy and without much lines of implementation code.